# Nested for loop through json object array does not work

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested-loops

I need to build a new array based on json array (Context) bellow. Unfortunately I never reach the outer Loop after passing by first run. Is there any mistake in code? How can I solve this issue?

Thank you for help.

Context:

```
"rfqBp": [
    {
      "rfqBpId": 1041650,
      "Contact": [
        {
          "ID": 1000014,
          "SelectedContact": true
        },
        {
          "ID": 1002411,
          "SelectedContact": true
        },
        {
          "ID": 1016727,
          "SelectedContact": true
        },
        {
          "ID": 1017452,
          "SelectedContact": true
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "rfqBpId": 1052326,
      "Contact": [
        {
          "ID": 1016236,
          "SelectedContact": true
        },
        {
          "ID": 1019563,
          "SelectedContact": true
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "rfqBpId": 1056632,
      "Contact": [
        {
          "ID": -1,
          "SelectedContact": false
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "rfqBpId": 1056637,
      "Contact": [
        {
          "ID": 1019875,
          "SelectedContact": true
        }
      ],
    }
  ],
```

**script:**

```
$scope.SelectedContacts = function() { //function starts by click on checkbox in html
  let selectedContactList = [];
  let finalList = [];
  $scope.Context.Output = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= $scope.Context.rfqBp.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= $scope.Context.rfqBp[i].Contact.length; j++) {
      if ($scope.Context.rfqBp[i].Contact[j].SelectedContact === true) {
        selectedContactList = {
          "ID": $scope.Context.rfqBp[i].Contact[j].ID
        };
        finalList.push(selectedContactList);

      } else if ($scope.Context.rfqBp[i].Contact[j].SelectedContact !== true) {
        continue;
      }
      $scope.Context.Output = finalList; //Output works but just for rfqBp[1]
    };
  };
  $scope.Context.Output = finalList; //this part never reached
};
```

**Output:**

```
  "Output": [
    {
      "ID": 1000014
    },
    {
      "ID": 1016727
    },
    {
      "ID": 1017452
    }
  ]
```

**I try to get following:**

```
  "Output": [
    {
      "ID": 1000014
    },
    {
      "ID": 1016727
    },
    {
      "ID": 1017452
    },
    {
      "ID": 1016236
    },
    {
      "ID": 1019563
    },
    {
      "ID": 1019875
    }
  ]
```

Comment: The only way you could not get to that statement is if there's an error that stops the loops.  Is there any error message in the console?

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). Your various "before" structures start in the middle of something, which makes it very hard to help you.

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: you are overwriting `$scope.Context.Output = finalList;` each iteration

Comment: @johnSmith But he's pushing onto `finalList` each iteration.

Comment: `<=` should be `<`. You're accessing outside the array and getting an error.

Comment: Thank you for help! I replaced <= with < in both loops and now I get the expected output. Unfortunately I got no error message because of the framework.

Comment: What is the condition to exclude the `ID` with value `-1`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) combined with [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const rfqBp = [{rfqBpId: 1041650,Contact: [{ID: 1000014,SelectedContact: true,},{ID: 1002411,SelectedContact: true,},{ID: 1016727,SelectedContact: true,},{ID: 1017452,SelectedContact: true,},],},{rfqBpId: 1052326,Contact: [{ID: 1016236,SelectedContact: true,},{ID: 1019563,SelectedContact: true,},],},{rfqBpId: 1056632,Contact: [{ID: -1,SelectedContact: false,},],},{rfqBpId: 1056637,Contact: [{ID: 1019875,SelectedContact: true,},],},]

const result = rfqBp
  .flatMap(({ Contact }) => Contact
    .filter(({ ID }) => ID > 0) // Filter to exclude negative `ID`s
    .map(({ ID }) => ({ ID }))
  )

console.log(result)
```